# Pytesseract image_to_string method not returning expected output

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've been trying all possible combinations of settings.. 
I'm trying to extract the timestamp from a video.

Made a copy around the timestamp , tried to apply all sorts of filters , making the text black with erosion. Nothing works .. it's a really simple straightforward image with clear digits inside.  I thought it would be a walk in the park for tesseract to extract info from this kind of image.

This is the code I've tried , also tried different PSM options to no avail. It's mostly returning letters instead of digits or nothing at all.

```
upper_left2 = (530, 40)
bottom_right2 = (650, 170)

# r = cv2.rectangle(img, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 200), 5)
# r2 = cv2.rectangle(img, upper_left2, bottom_right2, (100, 50, 200), 5)
region_1 = img[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] : bottom_right[0]]
region_year = img[upper_left2[1] : bottom_right2[1], upper_left2[0] : bottom_right2[0]]

img_scaled =  cv2.resize(region_year, None, fx=1, fy=1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

imggray = cv2.cvtColor(region_year, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img2 = cv2.dilate(imggray, kernel, iterations=1)
img3 = cv2.erode(img2, kernel, iterations=1)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img3, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

img3[thresh == 255] = 0

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
erosion = cv2.erode(img3, kernel, iterations = 1)


# text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img3, config=config)
ocr_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(imggray, lang='eng')

print(ocr_result)
```

This is the output of img3 -> 
[image]

This is the output of erosion -> [image]

[image]

The original image from the video looks like this

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `img3`?

Comment: Hello , thank you added more info. Hmm it definitely a bit unclean but not sure how to fix it to make it more readable by image_to_string. I'm thinking maybe to go another route and just call this API instead ? https://api.ocr.space/parse/imageurl?apikey=helloworld&url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QBPJ.png

Comment: Sure, that's an option. The main issue with your preprocessing is that in the end you `NEED` to get binarized data with 2018 in black and everything else in white (not gray) - and I don't see you doing that.